# For the life of me I can't get this to print the "hobbies" on individual lines?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

```
 people = [
  {
    "first_name" => "Robert",
    "last_name" => "Garcia", 
    "hobbies" => ["basketball", "chess", "phone tag"]
   },
  {
    "first_name" => "Molly",
    "last_name" => "Barker",
    "hobbies" => ["programming", "reading", "jogging"]
   },
  {
    "first_name" => "Kelly",
    "last_name" => "Miller",
    "hobbies" => ["cricket", "baking", "stamp collecting"]
   }
]

index = 0
while  index < "hobbies".length
  p people[index]["hobbies"]
  index += 1
end
```



With the class I'm taking they want me to use the `p` statement not `puts` and it wants me to run it as a loop I don't understand what the "undefined method '[]'" is can anyone shine some light on this and walk me through it as simply as possible?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a single quote in front of `people`?

Comment: no that was just me formatting it to put it in as a question

Comment: I feel very dense with all of this I feel like it should jump out and bite me but this is only my second week of pre work before my live classes start and this whole section has me feeling like I'm hitting a brick wall.c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are attempting to iterate through `people` based on the length of the string `"hobbies"`. Now, that string has length 7, but the `people` array only has length 3.

You either want:

```
index = 0
while  index < people.length
  p people[index]["hobbies"]
  index += 1
end
```

Or better is to just used the `each` method.

```
people.each do |person|
  p person["hobbies"]
end
```

When I run this, I see:

```
irb(main):028:0> people.each do |person|
irb(main):029:1*   p person["hobbies"]
irb(main):030:1> end
["basketball", "chess", "phone tag"]
["programming", "reading", "jogging"]
["cricket", "baking", "stamp collecting"]
```

The reason you get the error you do can be shown with a very simple example:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = [2]
=> [2]
irb(main):002:0> a.length
=> 1
irb(main):003:0> a[0]
=> 2
irb(main):004:0> a[1]
=> nil
```

When we access an array at an index that's out of bounds, we don't get an error. We just get `nil`. In your code, you try to subscript `nil` and that does cause the error you're seeing.

Comment: thank you so much I totally see it now. I still can't seem to get them to print on separate lines though?

Comment: I've edited to show the output. For me it does print on separate lines. Do you want a blank line between each one?

Comment: no I guess it is supposed to be like outside of the array each index on a separate line "basketball"
"chess"
"phone tag"
"programming"
"reading"
"jogging"
"cricket"
"baking"
"stamp collecting"        kind of like all in one column

Comment: That's the expected output if you use `p`. If you want them each on a line with an index, try: `person["hobbies"].each_with_index { |hobby, i| puts "#{i}. #{hobby}" }`

Comment: As long as you learned something, that's the important part.